# Authentication process with Auth0 moves the user away from our app and into another location

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0, auth0-delegated-admin

I am using Auth0 for authentication in my app, I've put the login button on the app's home screen , pressing the login button moves the user away from our app and into another location(Auth0 site), and then it takes us back after successful authentication. Is there any way of doing this with Auth0 that you stay within the app itself? That is, the user would not know that the app is using Auth0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming this is a web app you can use an Embedded Login by placing the Auth0 Lock widget on your page.  There are some security hoops you have to jump through if you do that (enable cross-origin authentication, use Custom Domain Names or assume your users have 3rd party cookies enabled, etc.).  There's a good pro/con explanation of the two approaches here:
https://auth0.com/docs/guides/login/universal-vs-embedded

Also, there may be some ways to roll your own UI and use the Auth0 API to authenticate.  The down side there is you may be introducing some security holes that Auth0 presumably wouldn't (since they're the security experts).

Answer (score 0):

I assume this app is a web application.
In that case you can use a [custom domain](https://auth0.com/docs/custom-domains). You can specify something like *login.example.com*. Where *example.com* is your app domain. Please note that custom domain feature is not available for free plan.